# Adding HTML5 audio as embedded mp3 data URI

Tags: base64, html5-audio, data-uri

I have an HTML audio element that plays a linked .mp3 file upon click:

```
<audio id="yourAudio" preload="none" onplay="playing(this);" onended="stopped(this);">
    <source src="/sandboxassets/pronunciations/esdar1e007.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I don't want to display the direct link to the audio file (`/sandboxassets/pronunciations/esdar1e007.mp3`) in the HTML source. Is there any way to obfuscate it? I know we can use base64 encoding to obfuscate image links turning them into data URIs but I don't know how to do the same with mp3 files, if at all that's possible. Also, will that be a wise move compatibility-wise?

Addition: For what it's worth, there could be up to 5 such audio elements on my page and each such element loads an mp3 of size between 8kB and 20kB. I am assuming this scenario should justify a higher file size vs. fewer HTTP requests tradeoff. But please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What language are you using in your web app?  You could obfuscate the server side link.

Comment: Why do you want to obfuscate it, and what and who do you *actually* want to protect against? People will always be able to tell the URL that's being fetched by going to the Network tab in the developer tools.

Comment: Most likely you can do the exact same thing, data URLs should be supported. But if the files are big, it's not that smart. But do understand that using base64 is not obfuscating links, it's *embedding the data into the URL*.

Comment: Excuse my choice of words. The intent is not to necessarily protect the file from being downloaded. I just want it to: a) not show the original mp3 filename, and b) embed the file within the HTML page so as to prevent subsequent requests to the server upon click.

Comment: The mp3 files in question could be anywhere between 8kB and 20kB. I am hoping this filesize should justify a bigger size vs. fewer requests tradeoff. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use data URIs to do this. Just put the data URI in your `src` value. For example:

```
<audio controls src="data:audio/ogg;base64,XXXXXX....." />
```

See [this page](https://iandevlin.com/html5/data-uri/audio.php) for a working example